# How Communicate 2 androids in an App ?

Tags: android, device, communication, google-play-games

I will create an Android App but I need help. I dont know how communicate two androids phones using an app.

For example, two players with 2 devices playing a game, when one device make some move, how can this move find the another android device to send it the move ?

Anyone can help me how to make this "talk" between two devices?

I have an idea on mind. I know google can help me with a ID of the device that have the app. With the Id Can i make it?

Thank you so much :)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

Comment: You will probably need a server to manage that interaction. Take a look into games engine also, it will make your like 'less hard'...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [Nearby Connections API](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/nearby).  This API enables communication between devices on the same WiFi network.

The nice thing is you don't need to sign into any servers to make it work; it is purely peer-to-peer.

The high level flow is:

1. One device calls startAdvertising() to be able to accept
   connections.
2. Other devices (there can be multiple devices) call
   startDiscovery() to find the devices that are advertising.
3. Once an
   advertising device is found, sendConnectionRequest() is called and
   the advertiser can accept or reject the connection.
4. After the
   connection is established, you can send messages.